# Data flowing in SSIS Dataflow task

Tags: ssis

HI I am unable to see the rows flowing in the Dataflow while running from visual studio in VS2013 not sure how to enable it.

I tried looking in tools options but didn't find any clue.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to see a preview of the data while running the package?

Comment: No option I am aware of, the row counts are always there for me, if there are rows present at all.   What have you done to confirm that rows are flowing, if you don't see row counts?   If they definitely are, then you might have some corruption in your package that prevents VS from being able to work correctly with it.

Comment: This is the situation in development. so i am changing the table structure  so it was dropped and recreated many a times and populated with the same package. So i check the row count every time i run the package. So Not sure  and didnt even find any help on google :-(

Answer (score 1):

Hi After a awful  lot of time found out that Microsoft have buggered up once again as the annotation colour is white and will not be able to  change it to any colour in the Dark Theme.

Found out from below  link

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/910798/ssis-annotations-in-ssdt-2013-invisible-in-dark-color-theme

Comment: So with a Dark Theme annotations are worthless.  Good times MS.

Answer (score 0):

In the data flow task, right click on the connector between the two components and click Enable Data Viewer

[image: Data Viewer]

When you next run the package a window will appear which shows the data being transfered between the components

Comment: Hi kzhen ! Sorry if my question was not clear. I wanted to see the number of rows flowing being displayed beside the path in dataflow task and not the actual data.

Comment: are you sure that there are actually rows of data flowing?

Comment: Yeah i am sure there are about 10 Million rows flowing it would be interesting to see the  rows flowing through. I thought there might a option to make it visible and invisible